# How to add Splash screen in ionic cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

```
I have installed plug-in for splash screen, 

$ ionic start myapp tabs
$ ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
$ ionic platform add android
$ vi config.xml

Changed config file as the following

Put the following preference elements in config.xml:

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />

In the <platform name="android">, put the <splash> elements in, but DO NOT include the file extension:

<splash src="res/screen/android/640x960" density="mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/768x1024" density="hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/1536x2048" density="xhdpi"/>
```

Only it is showing the white splash screen. I do not know where I went wrong? Someone help me to come out?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the value attribute. The value is the name of the specific image file being used as the splash in the resource folder. Sometimes its not called 'screen' but 'splash'.

To customize better you can also use resources in Ionic CLI
http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html